# Angular error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Id')

Tags: angular, typeerror

I am trying to display the values in the dropdown from which the values are fetched from API response. Below is my html:

```
<th><select class="form-control" id="deviceTypeFilter" ngIf="deviceType" ng-options="deviceType for deviceType in vm.deviceTypes" ng-model="vm.selectedDeviceType" ng-change="vm.loadWithFilters()"><option value=""></option></select></th>
```

Respective ts. file :

```
  export class FirmwaresController {
    isLoading: boolean = false;
    selectedDeviceType: string = null;
    selectedTenant: Tenant;

    deviceTypes: Array<string>;
    firmwares: Array<any>;
    firmwaresCnt: number;

    private logger: ILogger;

    constructor(private $stateParams: any,
      logger: LoggerService,
      private firmwareService: FirmwareService,
      private applicationService: ApplicationService,
      private modalService: ModalService,
      private $window: any,
      $scope: IScope) {

      this.setFilterCollections();
      this.loadFirmwares();
      this.selectedDeviceType = $stateParams.deviceType;
      this.applicationService.getCurrentTenant()
        .then((tenant) => {
          this.selectedTenant = tenant;
          this.loadFirmwares();
        })
        .finally(() => this.isLoading = false);
      this.logger = logger.getLogger('firmwares');
    }

    setFilterCollections() {
      this.firmwareService.getDeviceTypes(this.selectedTenant.Id).then((response: any) => this.deviceTypes = response);
    }

    loadFirmwares() {
      if (this.selectedDeviceType === null) {
        return;
      }
      this.isLoading = true;
      this.firmwares = new Array<any>();
      this.firmwareService.getFirmwares(this.selectedTenant.Id, this.queryFilter)
        .then((firmwares: Array<any>) => {
          angular.forEach(firmwares, (firmwares: any) => {
            this.firmwares.push(firmwares);
          });
        })
        .finally(() => this.isLoading = false);
    }

    loadWithFilters() {
      if (this.selectedTenant !== null) {
        this.currentPage = 1; // resetting to page 1 to avoid RangeNotSatisfiable errors
        this.loadFirmwares();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the error saying

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Id')
    at FirmwaresController.setFilterCollections (
```

I am new to Angular, and have gone through few documents and have checked possible solution, unfortunely i am not able to find the root cause.  Please help me to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems `this.selectedTenant` is `undefined`. Have you tried `console.log()` to check the value and assign the value to this variable before using it? While your question is *Angular* but not *AngularIS* which both are different frameworks.

Comment: @YongShun : I tried console.log(this.selectedTenant), I dont see the response in the inspect element. I think you are right this.selectedTenant is undefined. Can you please help me fix this.

Comment: You need to move `this.setFilterCollections();` &
      `this.loadFirmwares();` into your promise from `getCurrentTenant()` to set tenant before using it. Since both those functions reads your `selectedTenant.id`

Comment: @NilsKähler : Understood the concept now. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from your setFilterCollections() that tried to access selectedTenant property before you initialize this variable.

You must call this method after the result of your promise that retrieve the selected tenant :

```
this.applicationService.getCurrentTenant()
    .then((tenant) => {
      this.selectedTenant = tenant;
      this.setFilterCollections();
      this.loadFirmwares();
    })
    .finally(() => this.isLoading = false);
```

Comment: Understood the concept now! Thanks this worked :)